# Unable to scrape data from Crash. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'div'

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.roobet.com/crash")
time.sleep(3)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,features="html5lib")
crash = soup.find('div', class_ = 'MuiButton-label')
num = crash.div.text
num.replace('x','')
print(num)
```

[Picture of inspection and reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cZFQ.png)

The row continues to update after each round and my goal is to leave the code running and collect each multiplier and then end at a certain point with all of the multipliers collected.

Comment: You don't need bs4. Just [wait for required element](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) and get data with WebElement `text` property

Comment: Thanks for the response! I understand what you are saying with not using bs4. Although how would I continually scrape away data as each round finished? I haven't found any such tutorials.

Comment: Which rows are you trying to scrape anyway?

Comment: @bilke , so in the picture you can see the multipliers that populate at the left and then move right 1 spot after each round. In the code these populate under each 'class="jss268 jss273"'. I hope that was able to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.get("https://www.roobet.com/crash")
time.sleep(3)
all_results = [mltp.text for mltp in driver.find_element_by_class_name("jss110").find_elements_by_class_name("jss111")]
print(all_results)
```

You could refresh this list every once a while to update your data